# Close chrome custom tabs from external in Android

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

Is it possible to close chrome custom tabs from the calling app using a timeout?

Scenario is the user being in a session which times out after 5 minutes. At this (variable) point in time I'd like to close the chrome custom tab (if it is open) no matter what state it is in.

Developing for android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the current time, the Custom Tab API do not allow the host app to close it programmatically.